# Can i trigger an email to be sent when info in a column is changed on excel?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am trying to use power automate to send a email if a column is changed from 'No' to 'Yes', or if the column already read 'Yes' and other columns have been altered.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Look into [Worksheet change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change).

Comment: The answer is yes and no. There are no change events from PowerAutomate that target individual cells but using the SharePoint file modified event and if you’re smart enough, you’d be able to orchestrate something. It may be a little clunky though.